# creating hyperlinks in python

Tags: python, html, url, hyperlink

I have a log file in which some test commands and their status (Pass/Fail) are logged using python. Now I want that test commands should not be written as simple text but should be written as hyperlinks. So that when I click on them another files which are linked to them are opened.

For e.g:

```
file = open("C:/logfile.log", "w")
file.write("[Command Name - '%35s']    [PASSED]\n" %(CommandName))
file.close()

file1 = open("C:/TestCommand.log/", "w")
file1.write("'%35s \n" %(str(parameter_val_for_test_command)))
file1.close()
```

Now I want that the CommandName written in logfile.log should be a hyperlink for the file TestCommand.log So that when I click on the CommandName the file TestCommand.log opens.

Can you please suggest how should I do create a logfile.log with hyperlinked CommandName and then how should I link this hyperlinked CommandName to the file TestCommand.log??

Comment: What application are you using when you click on the hyperlink?

Comment: There's no such thing as a hyperlink in a text file. A text file just has text. You can write syntax for a hyperlink, say using HTML -- is that what you mean?

Comment: I have not yet created the hyperlink. Thats what I want to know that how should I create this hyperlink for CommandName and then how should I link it to the file TestCommand

Comment: @katrielalex: So you mean that I should create logfile.html and then create hyperlinks for CommandName to link them to TestCommand.html file??

Comment: There is no magical sequence that turns any text into a hyperlink. It is up to the program you view the text in to interpret certain text format as a hyperlink. So to answer your question you must know the expected log file format. (And once you know it you'll probably be able to answer your question without help).

Comment: Like @atzz says - it all depends, if I just use bash and `tail somefile.txt` and it contains `http://www.google.com is a search engine` I can hover and click the link, but it won't appear as clickable until hovered over.. If opened in something else, it could well be...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about what a hyperlink, well, *is*.

A text file is a file containing text. (It's simple, but it needs to be said!) It doesn't have pictures, animations, colours, headers, or anything like that. It's just text.

Since people often want more data with their text (x should be a heading, y should be red, z should make a funny cursor when you mouse over it), there are many schemes for encoding data about text. For example, [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is a text format used by StackOverflow. HTML is a markup language (a way of annotating text) that uses `<tag>` elements. It's useful because web browsers can take HTML pages as input and display them graphically.

A hyperlink as you describe it is a graphical element such as you might find on a website. You can't have them in a text file, because a text file is *just text*. But you can instruct a web browser to display a hyperlink by writing

```
<a href="where/you/want/the/link/to/go">text of the link</a>
```

If you open a file containing that in a web browser, it will display the text as a link. Note that files containing HTML are conventionally called `something.html` to indicate their contents, and that there are a bunch of required tags in any HTML document (`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`).

Answer (score 13):

> **Creating hyperlinks in Python?**

This is fairly trivial, as a hyperlink is of the format:

```
hyperlink_format = '<a href="{link}">{text}</a>'
```

One can parameterize this easily in Python. Here's several methods for doing so:

#### Call the .format method from the string

```
>>> hyperlink_format.format(link='http://foo/bar', text='linky text')
'<a href="http://foo/bar">linky text</a>'
```

#### Use a bound `.format` object:

```
link_text = hyperlink_format.format
```

Usage:

```
>>> link_text(link='http://foo/bar', text='foo bar')
'<a href="http://foo/bar">foo bar</a>'
```

#### Make a partial function

```
import functools
link_text = functools.partial(hyperlink_format.format)
```

Usage:

```
>>> link_text(link='http://foo/bar', text='linky text')
'<a href="http://foo/bar">linky text</a>'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think use the function:

```
    hyperlink_format = '<a href="{link}">{text}</a>'
```

to a HTML file and in the HTML file type:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><script type="text/javascript">window.location="url";</script></html>
```

Comment: You should explain, how converting his log to an HTML format might be helpful rather than a file and in that way, he can add hyperlinks. Then I guess, the code would make sense.